# Moving a CCSprite and getting a callback

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, callback, ccaction

I move an instance of `CCSprite` in my Cocos2D-based iPhone game like this:

```
[mySprite runAction:[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1.0 
                                        position:ccp(10, 10)]];
```

How can I get a callback everytime the sprite moves?

I'd like to do something like this:

```
[self registerForCallbacksFrom:mySprite 
                      selector:@selector(spriteMovedOneStep)];
```

So `spriteMovedOneStep` would be called everytime mySprite moves. Would be nice to specify the frequency of the callback too so minimize CPU usage.

Comment: Do you want the callback every frame while the sprite is moving, or once when the move ended? The former is a matter of setting "isMoving" in an ivar and process that in the normal update method.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I'd like the callback every frame (or every other frame). I've used `CCSequence` and `CCCallFunc` to handle the latter case you mentioned. Also I'm curious because I don't need the normal update method most of the time. Just for short bursts. So I suppose scheduling/unscheduling some selector could work.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to subclass CCMoveBy and call your callback from it's update method. You also can setup frequency and everything you want with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question right you would like to have a method called at times when the Sprite is moving, correct ?
How about scheduling an update method that performs what you want if a **SpriteIsMoving BOOL** is set to YES, I'm not sure on what your trying to achieve but this is my take on it.

Comment: You're understanding is correct and that's basically what I do. When the sprite starts moving I schedule a selector `handleMovingSprite`. When the sprite stops moving I unschedule the selector. To be safe I make sure the moving sprite exists before I use it (in the selector).